# What is wrong with below circuit simulation of RC filter with rectified AC input?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, rectifier

I am trying to find the average rectified AC output from a bridge rectifier output and the simulation results do not seem to match with the theoretical calculations well.

**Should n't the RC circuit act as a low pass filter and provide the average of input signal, if the fsignal>>cut off freq?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Quantity the error you see, please. It will help me be sure I know what two numbers you compare and imagine as a problem.

Comment: The value differs by 40mV which is less than 1.5% error. What formulas did you use in the theoretical calculations and where does your simulation differ?

Comment: @Justme Yeah. I'm still waiting for a number from the OP. But that was my guess. Anyway, that could be due to the RC itself or to the maximum step in time precision used. I didn't want to bother debugging until the OP confirmed what exactly they were looking at. I don't have a working crystal ball, sadly. And I'm not going to guess here.

Comment: Yes, The capacitor dc voltage(average) is where I see the mismatch. It is only 40mV difference, but this is being given as an input to a comparator.

Would be better if the precision is improved.

Comment: @DivyaK.S Yeah. I want to use some very strong language right now about your methods. But I'll hold short. Everyone learns as they can. [Here's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tdh2.png) with a 1 microsecond stepping. Same circuit, exactly. Getting mentally hung up over such simplistic numerical errors using Spice is something you cannot afford. You need to shake yourself of them. And now. Not later.

Comment: @DivyaK.S There are also times to consider `.options plotwinsize=0`. LTspice uses lossy compression. *(I'm guessing that this comes from a time when our disk drives were tiny things -- not the terabyte monsters we have today.)* That option says, *"Number of data points to compress in one window. Set to zero to disable compression."* Having no lossy compression can be a good thing, at times. Today, you should just probably use it all the time and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, fixed the time step and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to minimize the non-linearity of the diodes; you need a linear low-impedance source before the filter. You can do this by adding another resistor and making R3 much larger than R2.

If you need a perfect average, you will need to add an active buffer before the filter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv0m9B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Added R3( tried 80k and 800k), but no difference in results.

Comment: @DivyaK.S Yeah. Change your step size.